# fadeIn fadeOut, it's not being triggered all the time

Tags: jquery, triggers, fadein, fadeout

I'm doing a basic .bind(), placing fadein and fadeout on mouseover and mouseleave,
but it doesn't work all the times. I'm not finding the issue, so I need help or a better sugestion to do this. Thanks for looking, the pastie here http://pastie.org/1433800 and can also check the code below:

```
        $(function()
        {
            $('#mi_green_media').bind({

                mouseover : function() 
                {
                    $('#sub_menu_content').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn(1000);
                }

            });

            $('#sub_menu_content').bind({

                mouseleave : function()
                {
                    $('#sub_menu_content').css('visibility','hidden').fadeOut(1000);
                }

            });

        }
    );
```

Comment: At what moment do you call this function to bind the events. Maybe the bind is not always executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) automatically set the visibility for you.  All you need to do is

```
$('#sub_menu_content').fadeIn(1000);
```

and

```
$('#sub_menu_content').fadeOut(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bind() try the live() method too. it attaches a " handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future"
[link text](http://api.jquery.com/live/)